# Family 2 adults and 3 children visiting Yellowstone National Park

Tags: usa, children, weather-and-climate, yellowstone

I am starting to plan a trip to the USA, there are 5 things I would like to see,
the distances are not like Europe, everything seems to be so far from each other.

In order to ask an objective question I will just ask about the Yellowstone National Park:

Are there activities for children?

I have 2 girls less than 2 years old, and 1 boy 5 years old that really loves nature and insects specially, me and wife love the nature but we are concerned about the children there.

how many days for a relaxed experience of the Yellowstone National park, keeping the children ok?

I know there is a degree of opinion base on this question, let me re-frase it:

what are the good points that Yellowstone has to offer to family visitors?

What time of the year - we haven't as yet decided it but we're following this:

[What time of the year is the weather warm enough for camping in Yellowstone National Park?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85680/what-time-of-the-year-is-the-weather-warm-enough-for-camping-in-yellowstone-nati)

[image]

Comment: https://www.nps.gov/yell/learn/kidsyouth/index.htm

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's a very useful link, I had not seen before!

Comment: @MichaelHampton want to expand that into a useful answer? :D